# Verilog Netlist format with "\"

Tags: verilog, xilinx, cadence

After synthesizing my RTL level design into verilog netlist, I find the syntax confusing. Here is what I mean.

RTL compiler gives me:

```
  MUX2X1 g11005(.A (n_741), .B (\in_a[9] ), .S (n_2197), .Y (n_1063));
```

What is "\in_a[9]"?

XST gives me:

```
  wire [1 : 0] \inv/qmul/p ;
```

What is "\inv/qmul/p"?

Are "\" and "/" even eligible in verilog naming conventions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verilog escaping mechanism is to put \ at the start of an identifier and a " " at the end. The trailing space is mandatory. Within those, anything is a legal verilog name. It's pretty ugly.

It looks like the compiler has "flattened" part of the design, what might have been inv.qmul.p has become one identifier and the module hierarchy has gone.

Answer (score 3):

The `\` is an escape character, which escapes the entire string of ascii characters until the next space character (note the space before the closing parenthesis of .B).

So `\in_a[9]`, is literally just a net named `in_a[9]`. It's no longer part of any bus, it's just a net name that happens to have some brackets in it. Similar for `inv/qmul/p`, this is just a net name with some slashes in it (I've seen synthesizers generate nets like this when it wants to preserve a net's original hierarchy for some reason, though I couldn't say exactly why).

I *think* that you could have a verilog net named `wire \@#$%{{[[@#$^@ ;` and it wouldn't complain, but of course I've never tried :)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am not sure if \in_a[9] is a net named in_a[9], because I stimulate a design in modelsim, and it tells me that I have a signal called "\in_a[9]". It looks like that is the name of the signal.

Answer (score 1):

See the clunky [Verilog Formal Syntax Specification](http://www.verilog.com/VerilogBNF.html#REF170) for `<IDENTIFIER>`

> An identifier is any sequence of letters, digits, dollar
>   signs ($), and    underscore (_) symbol, except that the first must be a
>   letter or the     underscore; the first character may not be a digit or
>   $. Upper and lower case   letters are considered to be different.
>   Identifiers may be up to 1024     characters long. Some Verilog-based
>   tools do not recognize  identifier    characters beyond the 1024th as a
>   significant part of the identifier. Escaped   identifiers start with
>   the backslash character () and may include any   printable ASCII
>   character. An escaped identifier ends with white space. The   leading
>   backslash character is not considered to be part of the identifier.

Taking your example `wire [1 : 0] \inv/qmul/p ;`. The wire is named `inv/qmul/p`, typical of a hierarchical (modular) design being flattened.

Since `inv/qmul/p` is not a valid 'bare literal' in Verilog (due to the forward slashes) it is written as an escaped identifier. The escape mechanism is to prefix with backslash `\` and append whitespace .