# Verilog netlist module instance starts with \

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a netlist exported from Innovus, and some module instance names start with `\` .

```
DFRRQ_3VX1 \cnt_reg_reg[0]  (...)
```

In the testbench, I am forcing a module's input value, and it returns:

> Hierarchical name lookup error

```
force DUT.cnt_reg_reg[0].D = 1'b1;
```

I saw a [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/64304/verilog-netlist-format-with) about Verilog naming syntax, but I don't know how to implement it to do a hierarchical lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This instance name is known as an *escaped identifier*.  To avoid the error, you need to use the backslash and a space:

```
   force DUT.\cnt_reg_reg[0] .D = 1'b1;
```

Here is a complete code example:

```
module DUT;
    DFRRQ_3VX1 \cnt_reg_reg[0] ();
endmodule

module DFRRQ_3VX1 (input D);
    initial #1 $display("%m D=%b", D);
endmodule

module tb;
   initial begin
       force DUT.\cnt_reg_reg[0] .D = 1'b1;
       #5 $finish;
   end
endmodule
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 12.4 *Hierarchical names*:

> The period character shall be used to separate each of the names in
> the hierarchy, except for escaped identifiers embedded in the
> hierarchical name reference, which are followed by separators composed
> of white space and a period-character.

Also refer to section 2.7.1 *Escaped identifiers*:

> *Escaped identifiers* shall start with the backslash character (\) and
> end with white space (space, tab, newline). They provide a means of
> including any of the printable ASCII characters in an identifier (the
> decimal values 33 through 126, or 21 through 7E in hexadecimal).

The code runs on multiple simulators on [EDAPlayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/WeiS)